# App is Crashing on Adding new Fragments for Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am having a problem while adding Navigation Bar Activity fragments. I am using the default Navigation Bar provided in Android Studio with use of fragments. Initially, the code in `MainActivity.java` was (Working Fine) :

```
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }
```

But after modifying it to  show specific fragment on navigation drawer item selected, I added the following code instead of above code & the app is **crashing**. :

```
    @Override
   public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        switch(position){
            default:
            case 0:
                fragment=new MyFragment1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment=new MyFragment2();
                break;


        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

***Additional Information:***
I have created 2 fragments (MyFragment1 & MyFragment2) through File->New->Fragment->Fragment (Blank).

*There are no syntax errors*

**Log if needed :**

```
11-28 15:12:17.137  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-28 15:12:17.177  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer
11-28 15:12:17.177  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
11-28 15:12:17.177  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
11-28 15:12:17.197  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
11-28 15:12:17.197  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
11-28 15:12:17.197  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14530: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
11-28 15:12:17.197  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-28 15:12:17.197  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
11-28 15:12:17.197  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14534: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
11-28 15:12:17.197  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-28 15:12:17.207  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/dalvikvm﹕ GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getTotalMemory ()J
11-28 15:12:17.207  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/dalvikvm﹕ GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getFreeMemory ()J
11-28 15:12:17.237  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-28 15:12:17.237  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 416: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-28 15:12:17.237  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-28 15:12:17.237  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-28 15:12:17.237  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 438: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-28 15:12:17.237  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-28 15:12:17.297  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-28 15:12:17.297  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415f5d58)
11-28 15:12:17.297  26622-26622/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer, PID: 26622
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer/com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer.MainActivity@424062c8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer.MainActivity@424062c8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
            at com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer.MyFragment1.onAttach(MyFragment1.java:83)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:849)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:690)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1449)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code for `MyFragment1.java`

```
package com.example.harni_000.navigationdrawer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MyFragment1.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MyFragment1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MyFragment1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MyFragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MyFragment1 fragment = new MyFragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public MyFragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_fragment1, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Mike M. Little more details needed.. I am newbie to android.

Comment: The error is on line 83 of the `MyFragment1` class. You're trying to implicitly cast something to the wrong type. Please post the relevant code, if you need more details.

Comment: I have provided the code now.

Comment: Oh, you just need your Activity to `implements MyFragment1.OnFragmentInteractionListener`, and contain the `public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri)` method. Or, if you don't need a callback to the Activity from the Fragment, you can just remove the interface, `mListener`, and the `onAttach()` method.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: Can you please answer the question if you know, instead of commenting? :)

Comment: I can't. I don't know what syntax errors you're getting. The answer is that your Activity is apparently not implementing the interface correctly. If you need specifics, you'll have to post your code as it is now, pointing out exactly what your IDE is complaining about. You haven't even mentioned which option you're going with; removing the interface altogether, or correctly implementing it.

Comment: Thanks..It has started working..By simply removing `onAttach()` function from both the Fragment Java Files its working. :)